# How to assign same type as one of the type member?

Tags: typescript

For example, I have this code:

```
interface DbType {
    id: string,
}

interface RowType extends DbType {
    name: string
}

class db<T> { // How do I put that it must be an extension of DbType?

    insert(item: T) { }
    delete(id: [typeof id]) { } // What should I put here?
}
```

So when I do `new db<RowType>()` I want the `delete` method would accept the same type as `DbType.id`

How to do that?

Comment: Please ask one thing at a time, and research first - e.g. the first part is answered by https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a simple [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) and an [Indexed Access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content) for the `delete` parameter.

```
interface DbType {
  id: string;
}

interface RowType extends DbType {
  name: string;
}

class DB<T extends DbType> {
  insert(item: T) {}
  delete(id: T["id"]) {} 
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?isolatedModules=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCICMAqBPADigbwChllgATALmQGcwpQBzAbiIF8ijRJZEUAlAPYB3HPmQQAHpBDkaaLHkIlkIOAFsI1OgxAt2nBABs4NeagBCAHkwTpEWecX4AfMmKlQNaGAAUwSHVqTABKdw5ScggjCEh-KmRMAG0AIgoUgF0wgjZkAyA)